# Firebase send user to user notification without using cloud function or personal server

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification to another user with firebase messaging.
The most used way for this is to use cloud function with respective user token...

Is there any way we can exclude cloud function or personal server from this process. So that one user can send notification to another user if they had token of that particular user without going through server?

Comment: This isn't a supported case, because it requires that the client app know the private server key used to invoke the FCM APIs.  That's a huge security hole, as it effectively gives anyone the ability to send messages to anyone else using your app.

Comment: please clear me on that security issue: The other way is I can make a database and pass on notification to that database then cloud function will send it to desired destination. Why this not a security issue because with this too we can call that cloud function to send to anyone?

Comment: A Cloud Function (or any backend) can validate that the user invoking the function is allowed to send the message.  You control what it does, and it can't be compromised since your control its access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is not possible as it would require API key as mentioned by Doug in the comment. and putting that in client code would make blunder.

i m just making a guess and it is quite off topic but it might help someone in future if you dont want to read user FCM id again and agin from firestore as it might increase bill. you can create topics in FCM and subscribe the client to it. this way you can reduce the number of reads and suffice the purpose.

[FCM Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: please clear me on that security issue: The other way is I can make a database and pass on notification to that database then cloud function will send it to desired destination. Why this not a security issue because with this too we can call that cloud function to send to anyone?

just call the cloud function with right token and notification and you would be able to send message.